# How to open TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity

In my app, I want it to go to my main activity when user pushes hardware menu button options. But my main activity is a `TabActivity`. You will understand it better if you see the code.

The problem is I made a menu item which should start the main activity when user a clicks it. But I get an error when I click on it and forces to close. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menuhome:
                Intent i = new Intent("com.eran.exampleapp.MYMAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(i);
                break;
}
return false;
            }
```

and my main activity:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends TabActivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... why are you using upper case like this: `MYMAINACTIVITY`? Isn't your activity called `MyMainActivity`? Does it make sense for you?

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
return true;
```

Comment: Thanks mate it worked! And i ve learned another thing. Thanks a lot!